# How to groupBy one column and count another column with condition in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table for students with column `remarks` which is equal to `pass` or `fail` and a column `class` to determine their group.

Now I want to get a collection using eloquent that goes like:

```
Select count(remarks) where 'remarks' equal to pass and   
count(remarks) where 'remarks' equal to fail  
GROUP BY class
```

What I have tried so far:

```
Student::where('remarks', 'pass')
        ->selectRaw('count(remarks) as passRemark')
        ->where('remarks', 'fail')
        ->selectRaw('count(remarks) as failRemark')
        ->groupBy('class')->get();
```

The above code doesn't seem to work and it returns nothing, it does work when using 1 `where` clause which is not what I intend to do and I tried adding another `where`, the query breaks.

Can anyone suggest the best approach for this?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should try this query, using `DB::raw()`, just to see whether it works or not, then you can rewrite using the built in methods from the ORM.

```sql
SELECT SUM((CASE WHEN remarks = 'pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS passRemark,
       SUM((CASE WHEN remarks = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) AS failRemark
GROUP BY class
```

Answer (score 2):

To keep this in Eloquent, I would use the built in Laravel `withCount()` method and a closure function for each type of count.

Something like this would be my preference (I have now successfully tested this: each Student will have a count for both):

```
Student::withCount(['remarks as passRemark' => function ($query) {
         $query->where('remarks', 'pass');
}, 'remarks as failRemark' => function ($query) {
         $query->where('remarks', 'fail');
}])->groupBy('class')->get();
```